# Why my images are always uploaded in the first question of the form?

Tags: angular

I have inputs inside the questions but if I upload any in the second or third question, it always shows the image as an option of the first question. It seems that it is always taking the position [0] of the questions and not the question in which I am inserting the image.

```
public addOptionImage(question: QuestionModel, e: Event): void {
  if (question.type == "MultipleChoice" || question.type == "SingleChoice") {
    if (!question.options) {
      question.options = [];
    }
    console.log("question: ", question.description);

    const file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (file) {
      // debugger;
      console.log(file);
      let option = new QuestionOptionModel({
        description: file.name,
        imageData: file.name,
      });
      // question.options.push(
      //   new QuestionOptionModel({
      //     description: file.name,
      //   })
      // );

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        option.imageData = reader.result as string;
        console.log(option.imageData);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      //question.options.push(option);

      this.uploadForm.patchValue({
        image: file,
      });
      this.uploadForm.get("image").updateValueAndValidity();

      //test
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

      const qi = this.test.questions.indexOf(question);
      console.log(qi);

      const optionInput = this.getQuestionOptionImageInput(
        qi,
        question.options.length - 1
      );
      optionInput.focus();
      optionInput.setSelectionRange(
        optionInput.value.length,
        optionInput.value.length
      );
    }
  }
}
```